# What is the complexity of a recurrent neural network?

Tags: neural-network

In particular, how much memory does a recurrent NN require as a function of the dataset size,number of nodes, etc., and how expensive is it to evaluate at runtime given a new test point?

Answer (score 1):

I've found some time ago two interesting papers about recurrent neural networks and their complexity. I guess you can use those as a reference points at least:

- [Architectural Complexity Measures of Recurrent Neural Networks](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.08210v2.pdf)
- [Bounds on the complexity of recurrent neural network implementations of finite state machines](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/822-bounds-on-the-complexity-of-recurrent-neural-network-implementations-of-finite-state-machines.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the excellent references given by `sebap123`, from the [Deep Learning Book](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/) by Ian Goodfellow et.al,

> The recurrent neural network [given] is universal in the
> sense that any function computable by a Turing machine can be computed by such
> a recurrent network of a finite size. **The output can be read from the RNN after
> a number of time steps that is asymptotically linear in the number of time steps
> used by the Turing machine and asymptotically linear in the length of the input**
> .

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had to re-read that quote to figure out the link to the question . . . theoretical comparisons to a Turing machine are some steps away from specifics in the question, such as number of nodes vs memory use.

Comment: My bad, I should have read the question details. I was thinking about asymptotic complexity.

Comment: Well I guess if someone searches and finds this on the title alone, then they will find your answer which could be useful to them, so perhaps leave it as is.